# Using ctypes in background in Firefox WebExtension

Tags: firefox, jsctypes, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to write WebExtension for Firefox. Bassically, I need a working example how to run local programs from Firefox.

My current implementation of extension consist of:

- background.js
- content-scripts.js
- manifest.json

From webpage I am sending a message which handled by content-scripts.js who is forwarding it to background.js. But in msgbox function in background.js I unable to call ctypes. It gives me error:

*ctypes is not defined*

I tried to load ctypes different ways but it doesn't work:
`Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm")`
or
`var {ctypes} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm"`

What I do wrong?

Here is the source code of my extension.

**manifest.josn:**

```
    {
      "description": "Test web-extension.",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "Example",
      "version": "1.0",
      "homepage_url": "http://example.org",
      "icons": {
        "48": "icons/example-48.png"
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["*://web.localhost.com/*"],
          "js": ["content-scripts.js"]
        }
      ],
      "background": {
         "scripts": ["background.js"]
      },
      "applications": {
        "gecko": {
          "id": "example@mozilla.org",
          "strict_min_version": "45.0"
        }
      },

      "permissions": []
    }
```

**background.js:**

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msgbox());

    function msgbox() {
       var lib = ctypes.open("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\user32.dll");  

      /* Declare the signature of the function we are going to call */  
      var msgBox = lib.declare("MessageBoxW",  
                             ctypes.winapi_abi,  
                             ctypes.int32_t,  
                             ctypes.int32_t,  
                             ctypes.jschar.ptr,  
                             ctypes.jschar.ptr,  
                             ctypes.int32_t);  
      var MB_OK = 0;  

      var ret = msgBox(0, "Hello world", "title", MB_OK);  

      lib.close();  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use WebExtension APIs (on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions#Reference)) in your WebExtension. `Cu.import` and especially ctypes are not part of the WebExtension API, and so can't be used. You will probably have to wait for `chrome.runtime.connectNative` if you want to interact with OS level functions.

Comment: If I will try to implement browser-OS communication through "old" add-ons for Firefox (not via WebExtension), is it possible to use ctypes there?

Comment: Yes, both XUL (legacy) and Add-on SDK extensions support ctypes.